# Convert a List of Options to an Option of List using Scalaz

Tags: scala, option-type, scalaz, scala-option

I want to transform a `List[Option[T]]` into a `Option[List[T]]`. The signature type of the function is

```
def lo2ol[T](lo: List[Option[T]]): Option[List[T]]
```

The expected behavior is to map a list that contains only `Some`s into a `Some` containing a list of the elements inside the elements `Some`'s. On the other hand, if the input list has at least one `None`, the expected behavior is to just return `None`. For example:

```
scala> lo2ol(Some(1) :: Some(2) :: Nil)
res10: Option[List[Int]] = Some(List(1, 2))

scala> lo2ol(Some(1) :: None :: Some(2) :: Nil)
res11: Option[List[Int]] = None

scala> lo2ol(Nil : List[Option[Int]])
res12: Option[List[Int]] = Some(List())
```

An example implementation, without scalaz, would be:

```
def lo2ol[T](lo: List[Option[T]]): Option[List[T]] = {
  lo.foldRight[Option[List[T]]](Some(Nil)){(o, ol) => (o, ol) match {
    case (Some(x), Some(xs)) => Some(x :: xs);
    case _ => None : Option[List[T]]; 
}}}
```

I remember seeing somewhere a similar example, but using Scalaz to simplify the code. How would it look like?

---

A slightly more succinct version, using Scala2.8 `PartialFunction.condOpt`, but still without Scalaz:

```
import PartialFunction._

def lo2ol[T](lo: List[Option[T]]): Option[List[T]] = {
  lo.foldRight[Option[List[T]]](Some(Nil)){(o, ol) => condOpt(o, ol) {
    case (Some(x), Some(xs)) => x :: xs
  }
}}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There's a function that turns a `List[Option[A]]` into an `Option[List[A]]` in Scalaz. It's `sequence`. To get `None` in case any of the elements are `None` and a `Some[List[A]]` in case all the elements are `Some`, you can just do this:

```
import scalaz.syntax.traverse._
import scalaz.std.list._     
import scalaz.std.option._

lo.sequence
```

This method actually turns `F[G[A]` into `G[F[A]]` given that there exists an implementation of `Traverse[F]`, and of `Applicative[G]` (`Option` and `List` happen to satisfy both and are provided by those imports).

The semantics of `Applicative[Option]` are such that if any of the elements of a `List` of `Option`s are `None`, then the `sequence` will be `None` as well. If you want to get a list of all the `Some` values regardless of whether any other values are `None`, you can do this:

```
lo flatMap (_.toList)
```

You can generalize that for any `Monad` that also forms a `Monoid` (`List` happens to be one of these):

```
import scalaz.syntax.monad._

def somes[F[_],A](x: F[Option[A]])
                 (implicit m: Monad[F], z: Monoid[F[A]]) =
  x flatMap (o => o.fold(_.pure[F])(z.zero))
```

Comment: But if you want just the `Some` values of the `List[Option[A]]`, you don't need `Option` anymore. You'll have either an empty list or a nonempty list of `A`.

Comment: Actually, I do want to get `None` in case any of the elements are `None`, so `sequence` is exactly what I asked for.

I'll try to edit the question to clarify the requirement.

Comment: I can't get `lo.sequence` to work. Using scala-2.8.0.Beta1 and scalaz-core_2.8.0.Beta1-5.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar, if I enter `def lo2ol[T](lo: List[Option[T]]): Option[List[T]] = lo.sequence`, I get 
`<console>:10: error: diverging implicit expansion for type scalaz.Applicative[N]`

Comment: `import scalaz._; import Scalaz._; List(some(1), some(2), some(3)).sequence`. I get: `Some(List(1,2,3))`

Comment: Seth: This is odd. If you omit the return type, it works just fine. `def lo2ol[T](lo: List[Option[T]]) = lo.sequence`

Comment: Don't use scalaz-core_2.8.0.Beta1-5.0.1-SNAPSHOT, use scalaz-core_2.8.0.Beta1-5.0.0-SNAPSHOT. The former was inadvertantly published. https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/3152 is the likely cause of the problem.

Comment: I was able to get it working by using a recent Scala nightly which includes the fix for bug 3152. Thanks guys.

Comment: @Apocalisp: will this also work on `List[scala.concurrent.Future[T]]`?

Comment: @ErikAllik Yes it will.

Comment: @Apocalisp: did you mean Scalaz' Future? I'm getting `could not find implicit value for parameter G: scalaz.Applicative[G]`.

Comment: You will need an `Applicative[scala.concurrent.Future]`

Answer (score 20):

For some reason you dislike

```
if (lo.exists(_ isEmpty)) None else Some(lo.map(_.get))
```

?  That's probably the shortest in Scala without Scalaz.

Comment: Not bad, but it goes over the list twice.

Comment: @Apocalisp: Indeed, but that's almost always cheaper than making half of a new list before discarding it all and throwing back `None`.

Comment: wouldn't `if (lo contains None) None else Some(lo.flatten)` be even shorter?

Comment: @ErikAllik - Yes, slightly, though I'd avoid `flatten` because you convert the `Option` to a `List` along the way.  Good call on the `contains`, though.

Comment: @RexKerr: I was too lazy to keep thinking but I knew there was something sub-optimal about that `flatten`.

Answer (score 4):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, and the addition of the [`Option::unless`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/Option$.html#unless[A](cond:Boolean)(a:=%3EA):Option[A]) builder to the *standard library*, a variant to [Rex Kerr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2569812/9297144) would be:

```
Option.unless(list contains None)(list.flatten)
// val list = List(Some(1), Some(2))          =>    Some(List(1, 2))
// val list = List(Some(1), None, Some(2))    =>    None
```

or, if performance is at stake (in order to avoid `flatten`'s implicit conversion from `Option` to `List`):

```
Option.unless(list contains None)(list.map(_.get))
```

Answer (score 2):

While the `Applicative[Option]` in Scalaz has the wrong behaviour to directly use `MA#sequence`, you can also derive an `Applicative` from a `Monoid`. This is made convenient with `MA#foldMapDefault` or `MA#collapse`.

In this case, we use a `Monoid[Option[List[Int]]`. We first perform an inner map (`MA#∘∘`) to wrap the individual `Int`s in `List`s of one element.

```
(List(some(1), none[Int], some(2)) ∘∘ {(i: Int) => List(i)}).collapse assert_≟ some(List(1, 2))
(List(none[Int]) ∘∘ {(i: Int) => List(i)}).collapse                   assert_≟ none[List[Int]]
(List[Option[Int]]() ∘∘ {(i: Int) => List(i)}).collapse               assert_≟ none[List[Int]]
```

Abstracting from `List` to any container with instances for `Traverse`, `Pointed` and `Monoid`:

```
def co2oc[C[_], A](cs: C[Option[A]])
                  (implicit ct: Traverse[C], cp: Pointed[C], cam: Monoid[C[A]]): Option[C[A]] =
  (cs ∘∘ {(_: A).pure[C]}).collapse


co2oc(List(some(1), none[Int], some(2)))   assert_≟ some(List(1, 2))
co2oc(Stream(some(1), none[Int], some(2))) assert_≟ some(Stream(1, 2))
co2oc(List(none[Int]))                     assert_≟ none[List[Int]]
co2oc(List[Option[Int]]())                 assert_≟ none[List[Int]]
```

Sadly, trying to compile this code currently either triggers [#2741](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/2741) or sends the compiler into an infinite loop.

**UPDATE**
To avoid traversing the list twice, I should have used `foldMapDefault`:

```
(List(some(1), none[Int], some(2)) foldMapDefault (_ ∘ ((_: Int).pure[List])))
```

This answer was based on the original request that an empty list, or a list containing only `None`s, should return a `None`. Incidentally, this would be best modeled by the type `Option[scalaz.NonEmptyList]` -- `NonEmptyList` guarantees at least one element.

If you just want the a `List[Int]`, there are many easier ways, given in other answers. Two direct ways that haven't been mentioned:

```
list collect { case Some(x) => x }
list flatten
```

Comment: The real use-case behind this question is perfectly fulfilled by the `sequence` method in Apocalisp's answer, including the result when given an empty list (which may happen in said use case). But thanks for mentioning the NEL type, it looks handy.

Comment: @retronym: Rafael wrote "if the input list has at least one None, the expected behavior is to just return None". Where as you wrote "a list containing only Nones, should return a None". That's very different. "list flatten" doesn't do what Rafael actually asked for.

Comment: My bad, I mis-intperpreted the question. `MA#foldMapDefault` and `MA#sequence` both use `Traverse[List]`, but using a different Applicative Functors.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. I hope this is a correct solution.

It returns None if one of the Options in the List is None, otherwise it returns Option of List[A]

```
def sequence[A](a: List[Option[A]]): Option[List[A]] = {

  a.foldLeft(Option(List[A]())) {
    (prev, cur) => {

      for {
        p <- prev if prev != None
        x <- cur
      } yield x :: p

    }
  }

}
```