# Scala equivalent to Haskell's sequence

Tags: scala, functional-programming, type-conversion, scala-collections

Is there a Scala Library method that performs the conversion `Seq[Option[T]] -> Option[Seq[T]]`?

The Haskell equivalent would be `sequence :: Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]`.

Comment: In scalaZ you will find sequence. Other than that I think only Future got a sequence method.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6750609/2541573

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is unfortunately not available in the standard library (although there is a `Future.sequence`, as pedrofurla points out above). Part of the reason for this is probably just that the Scala standard library doesn't have any idea about applicative functors (or even monads, really).

As pedrofurla also mentions above, [Scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz) does provide `sequence`, and it's actually a lot more appropriately typed than Haskell's—instead of requiring something monadic inside a list as input, it accepts anything with an applicative functor instance inside something with a traversable instance (i.e., it's equivalent to `Data.Traversable`'s `sequenceA` in Haskell, not the `sequence` in the Prelude).