# Where is `sequence` in Scalaz7

Tags: scala, scalaz, scalaz7

I am learning Scalaz and I have a project that already makes use of Scalaz7. Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2569014/convert-a-list-of-options-to-an-option-of-list-using-scalaz) I would like to use the function

```
sequence[T](l: List[Option[T]]): Option[List[T]]
```

(not that it is hard to write it myself). But the aforementioned question mentions Scalaz6.

> Where to find the sequence function in Scalaz7?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's defined in the [`scalaz.Traverse`](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Traverse.scala) type class, where it looks like this:

```
def sequence[G[_]:Applicative,A](fga: F[G[A]]): G[F[A]] =
  traversal[G].run[G[A], A](fga)(ga => ga)
```

[`scalaz.syntax.TraverseOps`](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/syntax/TraverseSyntax.scala) provides a version that gets pimped onto `List`, since `List` has a `Traverse` instance.

You can either import just what you need:

```
import scalaz._, std.list._, std.option._, syntax.traverse._
```

Or everything and the kitchen sink:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
scala> val xs: List[Option[Int]] = Some(1) :: Some(2) :: Nil
xs: List[Option[Int]] = List(Some(1), Some(2))

scala> xs.sequence
res0: Option[List[Int]] = Some(List(1, 2))
```

Or if you want exactly the formulation in your question:

```
scala> def sequence[T](l: List[Option[T]]): Option[List[T]] = l.sequence
sequence: [T](l: List[Option[T]])Option[List[T]]

scala> sequence(xs)
res1: Option[List[Int]] = Some(List(1, 2))
```